# How to send SMS with team join url link from azure logic app design to user?

Tags: azure, chatbot, azure-logic-apps, azure-communication-services, power-virtual-agents

I have a scenario

1. Create power virtual agent chatbot using QNA
2. Connect human agent whenever customer need
3. Connect human-agent options to azure communication services

I have successfully created a chatbot,transfer context variables to omnichannels.
But my current case is to make human-agent experience with azure communication services.

So after some research i found a link  https://youtu.be/kCi1J4ayX0w which includes demo and flow of azure communication services with team call. The link is what i need. I created one azure communication service and i got a USA communication number in it.

My doubts,

1. How to make a audio/video microsoft teams join url link in azure logic app design?
2. How can I proceed it with power virtual agents?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you use sample payload to generate schema and add

   ```
   {
       "CustomerName":"",
       "joinUrl":"",
       "PhoneNumber":""
   }
   ```

   For Url, you can start a meet and click **Share Invite** then Copy the link and now you just have to add the URL while sending the HTTP request.

   [image]

   Here is the Sample pic where I was testing using API Tester.

   [image]
2. To proceed with power virtual agents you can refer to this [site](https://powerplatformtrainings.com/2020/12/28/integrate-power-virtual-agents-with-qna-maker-beginner-tutorials/).